# twrp problems flashing SuperSU

Tags: twrp

I try to install something like SuperSU. All it gives me is

```
Updating partition details...
...done
Full SELinux support is present.
Simulating actions...
Updating partition details...
...done
```

I press reboot system as up there it says "Successful".

When I get in the phone there is no SuperSU.

The zip file is ok, I tried it on another phone and it worked well.
Nothing on twrp works: no wipe no nothing, it just gives the above again.

Comment: Gonna need WAY more information than this... What device, Android version, TWRP version, SuperSU versions (SuperSU is largely depreciated BTW and most people use Magisk now)... What you are flashing, bootloader status, etc. Sorry, but with what you asked in your question it will likely be close as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

according to your logs TWRP is currently in simulation mode.

Updating partition details... ...done Full SELinux support is present. `Simulating actions`... Updating partition details... ...done

1) go to Settings

2) toggle simulation mode off.

Try to flash the .zip again. You should be good to go

Comment: @Wemmie In that case, you can hit the check mark in the left of this post (below arrow/voting buttons) to mark it as accepted. :)